# Errors running stored procedure in workbench

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure in MySQL workbench as below, and when I use

```
use stock_data;
call CreateStockTable;
```

command to call this procedure, it incurred an error:

```
16:09:29    call CreateStockTable   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8    0.016 sec
```

I want to create tables whose names start with data_60/data_00, and I wrote two while statements to do that. What's wrong with the code? Thanks.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CreateStockTable`()
BEGIN
DECLARE i int;     
DECLARE createSql VARCHAR(2560); 
DECLARE createIndexSql1 VARCHAR(2560);
DECLARE stockNum VARCHAR(4); 

set i=0; 
WHILE  (i< 3000) DO                     

      IF (i=0) THEN
      set stockNum='0000';
      ELSEIF (i<10) THEN
      set stockNum=CONCAT('000',i);
      ELSEIF (i<100) THEN
      set stockNum=CONCAT('00',i);
      ELSEIF (i<1000) THEN
      set stockNum=CONCAT('0',i);
      ELSE
      set stockNum=CONCAT('',i);
      END IF;

      SET createSql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_00',stockNum,'(
      id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
      date varchar(30),stock_code varchar(10),
      name varchar(20),P_close double,
      P_high double,P_low double,
      P_open double,P_percent double,
      volume int(11),turnover double,
      PRIMARY KEY (id,date)'
      ); 
      prepare stmt from @createSql; 
      execute stmt;                             
      SET i= i+1; 
END WHILE;

set i=0; 
WHILE  (i< 4000) DO                     
      IF (i=0) THEN
      set stockNum='0000';
      ELSEIF (i<10) THEN
      set stockNum=CONCAT('000',i);
      ELSEIF (i<100) THEN
      set stockNum=CONCAT('00',i);
      ELSEIF (i<1000) THEN
      set stockNum=CONCAT('0',i);
      ELSE
      set stockNum=CONCAT('',i);
      END IF;

      SET createSql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_60',stockNum,'(
      id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
      date varchar(30),stock_code varchar(10),
      name varchar(20),P_close double,
      P_high double,P_low double,
      P_open double,P_percent double,
      volume int(11),turnover double,
      PRIMARY KEY (id,date)'
      ); 
      prepare stmt from @createSql; 
      execute stmt;                             
      SET i= i+1; 
END WHILE;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors:

1. You must set the local variable `@createSql` before use that:

   ```
     SET @createSql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_00',stockNum,'(
     id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
     date varchar(30),stock_code varchar(10),
     name varchar(20),P_close double,
     P_high double,P_low double,
     P_open double,P_percent double,
     volume int(11),turnover double,
     PRIMARY KEY (id,date))'  /*add extra ) to fix create sql*/
     );
   ```

   You are using a declared variable `createSql`, it doesn't work.
2. You must deallocate the prepared statement:

   ```
    prepare stmt from @createSql; 
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;  /*<--  free used resources */
   ```